# What is the connection between Evolution, Berkeley DB and SQLite format 3 (Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS)

Tags: ubuntu, berkeley-db

I'm wondering what the connection is between Evolution Database Server (EDS), Berkeley DB and SQLite format 3.

When I look at the dependencies for EDS (for example [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/gnome/evolution-data-server)), I see that libdb5.3 (Berkeley v5.3 Database Libraries) is a dependency.

The [Syncevolution documentation](https://syncevolution.org/documentation/backends/) also states:

> In Evolution Data Server (EDS), depends on EDS backend. Local “file” backend (**Berkley DB for contacts**, iCalendar 2.0 .ics file for others) is tested

However, when I inspect a contacts database created with Evolution or Sycevolution, it says "SQLite format 3".

I'm wondering what the connection is here: Is Berkeley DB the same as SQLite 3, or has Berkeley DB been replaced by SQLite 3 in EDS? Or is there maybe some other explanation?

Answer (score 1):

This question was kindly answered today by someone on the Evolution users mailing list. I thought I'd share it here, in case someone else has the same question.

Berkeley DB was indeed replaced a few years ago with SQLite for EDS contacts.

Berkeley DB libdb is included only as a way to migrate old (Berkeley DB)
databases to the new format (SQLite3). The libdb dependency is optional and EDS can be built without it.